# How to access HTTP Requests made by web browsers in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, http

In VB.Net, how do I make a program to tap into the HTTP requests made by external web browsers?
I don't want to edit or stop the headers, only 'read' them, i.e., access its contents.
I'm speaking of something like Fiddler2, but I only want the 'reading' part.
I also want to read the user-agent.
How do I begin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is either a proxy server or a network sniffer.

I can't vouch for this proxy server, but a search returned http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/uploadfile/psingh/webserver04162005083342am/webserver.aspx.

For sniffing, take a look at Winpcap, such as http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4217/Packet-Sniffing-with-Winpcap-Functions-Ported-to-a.